# Magento 2: How to show address field in registration form?

Tags: magento2, php, customer, customer-account

I want to display address fields (to save in default billing address) in customer registration form. I know how to do in Magento 1. But I'm struck with Magento 2. Have anybody done this before ..?

Any xml file update like in magento 1,

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: You will have to pick up the address data through your observer and create the billing address record yourself. Why not to use a ready extension? For instance: https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-registration-fields-manager-customer-attributes.html

Comment: @Elavarasan, have you find solution? If Yes please post here. It can useful for others.

Answer (score 31):

[Example](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ShowAddressFields) display address fields using **customer_account_create.xml**:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Do you know how to achieve this in the latest release of Magento (v2.3.4)? I've used methods similar to your suggestion in the past and they've always worked, up until the release of 2.3.3.

Answer (score 9):

Create this file in your custom theme:

app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

So, you need to set the action method called **setShowAddressFields** like true, like that sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Worked for me on Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Comment: I could not see state dropdown in customer registration form after adding this code

Comment: I have been facing same issue as Jaimin State dropdown is not appearing proper after adding address fields for registration page.

Answer (score 3):

Never edit vendor files!!

Copy this in your theme and go on for there, i'm in search of the setting (backend) because why else would you code it like that?

If someone has found this let me know

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Hi first find magento root folder then vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout customer_account_create.xml then go to line no 13 check this code and put billow section on line no 17

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
                <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                    <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

use only this section

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields">
                        <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    </action>
```

Comment: You should NEVER edit vendor files as they can be overwritten. Use the answer given by wit.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout and open customer_account_create.xml.

Go to Line num 16 or find below code.

```
<container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
```

After below code just put below code.

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields">
                    <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argumen>
          </action>
```

After this you will see state dropdown in register page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for accomplish this,

1. From template file
2. From xml

Above explained `xml` way multiple times, so I'm going to do template file way.

Open template file inside your theme [Do not edit core files], **app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

**find line which has this code,**

```
getShowAddressFields()
```

it could be either in,

`<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>`

or

`<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>`

depending on your magento version.

**put this code before that line,**

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
```

So , final output should looks like this,

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

or

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```