# How to ask the customer to enter billing and shipping address while registering their account in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5, shipping-address, billing-address, create-account

I wish to get the billing address and shipping address while customer registering their account in Magento 2.

I just overrode the register.phtml & copied the address fields for both shipping and billing address separately.

1. While viewing in shipping address it is failed to show the state select box?

   2. If I get it separately, then how do I save it.

Please refer the attached screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to undo your template overrides.

Something like this should work

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128616/70343