# Why is the shipping form is display in register page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, register

- Where is config enable or disable the shipping address form in the Register page ?? Thanks!
  [image: eot2]

Comment: what want to you explain more ...

Comment: I want to enable the shipping address form on the Register page. Currently, I found the solution, thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **customer_accout_create.xml** you need to add:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
        <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Please check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105988/magento-2-how-to-show-address-field-in-registration-form) for more informations.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: glad i helped you :)